# Select last node from multiple parents

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following XML structure

```
<root>
 <entries>
  <object id="1">
   <value name="valName1">Text</value>
   <value name="valName2">Text</value>
   <value name="valName3">Text</value>
  </object>
  <object id="2">
   <value name="valName1">Text</value>
  </object>
  <object id="1">
   <value name="valName1">OtherText</value>
   <value name="valName2">Text</value>
  </object>
 </entries>
</root>
```

I want to end up with:

```
object: 1
valName1: OtherText
valName2: Text
valName3: Text

object: 2
valName1: Text
```

It is important that it returns the last data for the value node but it should get all the values from nodes where they exist...

Any ideas?

Comment: @user1040899, obviously XSLT!

Comment: @Peter, Can there be multiple <entries/> node? and do we have to merge them all!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in pure XSLT by grouping. In XLST 1.0 you would use Muenchian grouping, and in this case you need two lots of grouping. Firstly you would group by **object**, which means defining a key to look up **object** elements by ID

```
<xsl:key name="objects" match="object" use="@id" />
```

And to look-up the first element in each group (i.e. the unique object id), you would use the key like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="//object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('objects', @id)[1])]" />
```

Then, you are grouping by **value**, which means defining a key to look up **value** elements within their respective **object** elements

```
<xsl:key name="values" match="value" use="concat(../@id, '|', @name)" />
```

In this case, you really need the last element in each group, so you would use the key like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="//object[@id = $id]
      /value[generate-id() 
       = generate-id(key('values', concat($id, '|', @name))[last()])]">
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="objects" match="object" use="@id" />
   <xsl:key name="values" match="value" use="concat(../@id, '|', @name)" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('objects', @id)[1])]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="object">
      <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('object: ', $id, '&#13;')" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//object[@id = $id]/value[generate-id() = generate-id(key('values', concat($id, '|', @name))[last()])]">
         <xsl:sort select="@name" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ':', ., '&#13;')" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input XML provided, the following text is output:

```
object: 1
valName1:OtherText
valName2:Text
valName3:Text
object: 2
valName1:Text
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible, but I would say you are using XML incorrectly in a few ways. My understanding is that id tags are usually unique and the order the file comes in should not matter. Nevertheless, this is easily possible with Python.

Use a dictionary. Just go through the file and add objects to the dictionary as you find them. The "object" that you add will actually have the object id as an index and be a blank dictionary itself. Keep track of the current object you are inside and search every value tag, adding the value names and contents to the current object's dictionary. This will keep track of the latest data found.

As an alternative, you can wait until tomorrow when I will have time to write this for you (test in AP government tomorrow).